# Roll of the Dice

Tags: probability

For Hanukkah, you receive an infinite number of identical pairs of dice, pair A, pair B, pair C, pair D, pair E, etc.

You roll pair A. The sumtotal of the pair tells you how many times to roll pair B. Then you roll pair B that many times and add up their sumtotal which is how many times to roll pair C. The sumtotal of pair C tells you how many times to roll pair D. And so on.

How many pairs must you roll to have at least an n likelihood of having a grand sumtotal of at least m? Expressed in terms of n and m, with n expressing the likelihood as a value from 0 to 1, and m as the sumtotal is the pair's sumtotals taken together (sumtotal-pair-A + sumtotal-pair-B + sumtotal-pair-C ...etc).

Comment: Does the total of A get added to the rolls of B to get the number of times to roll C?  It sounds like not, but the total of A does go into the total to compare with $m$.  It doesn't make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 1):

A rough answer:  Once you get going, each pair of dice gets rolled a lot of times.  The sum of all the rolls will be close to $7$ times the number of rolls, so the number of rolls will multiply by about $7$ each time.  You need to roll the last pair of dice $\frac m7$ times (the earlier dice will contribute about $\frac 16$ of the last set), so need about $\log_7 \frac m7$ pairs of dice.